TypeScript project can't find UMD module during import
I created a library of React components built with TypeScript and compiled into UMD using Webpack. When I try to import one of those components into a separate TypeScript project, I get the following error:
Cannot find module <module_name> or its corresponding type declarations

I'm able to work around this by ignoring the import line using the // @ts-ignore comment or by adding declare module <module_name> in my project's declaration file; however, I'd prefer to just provide the typings as part of my component library. What is least amount of UMD-compliant code I have to add to get the project to find the component?
Update:
Adding accompanying .d.ts files with this:
declare module "..." {
  export = ...;
}

Seems to have fixed it, but is that right? When I use tsc to generate the files, they look different (just a simple import/export). Also, would this work if my project was a UMD module or something that doesn't inherently support import/export syntax or would the compiler take care of that?
